# VSTO Excel Add-In - WPF XAML Style issue

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, xaml

I am creating VSTO Office Excel-Add-In in which am popping up a simple WPF window. This window is styled with MahApps library. The issue is that no matter which approach I use, Icons while showing fine in the Visual Studio  preview, during Debug they are missing. The Icons.xaml which is responsible for showing Icons is installed in Resources folder, with Build action set to Page. Any thoughts about this issue?

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedSingleRowTabControl.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ExcelAddIn;component/Resources/Icons.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
```

I've tried also, without any success:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/ExcelAddIn;component/Resources/Icons.xaml" />

<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/component/Resources/Icons.xaml" />
```